# Restricting multiple users to commit changes to datalist at the same time (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, database, datalist

I have build a web application which shows the list of customers using datalist control of asp.net , Each customer can be updated, The issue is the application is used by multiple users for instance 5-6 at a time, The problem is when 5 users logged in at a same time they can view the same customer list and can make changes to the same customer at similar time,

Is it possible to restrict user from viewing one customer which is being viewed by other user, for instance if customer 1 is being watched and modified by user 1 then user 2,3,4 will not be able to see customer 1 in their list of customers.
Any assistance or tutorials will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 options: pessimistic concurrency or optimistic concurrency.

pessimistic con concurrency locks the entity while the user is viewing it. during this time no one else can access the entity. this works on a small scale, but will quickly become a bottleneck in larger systems.

optimistic concurrency uses a version number. any user can view the data. when changing the data the version number must match, otherwise a change has occurred. then you can notify the user of the change and let them decide to cancel or update. this scales very nicely, but requires a little more work to handle version conflicts.

Comment: In my situation , i want to hide that whole record from the user , if that record is displayed by other user

Comment: I don't know that I would go that far. users should be able to see the current state of the system, whether or not the information is being edited. the fact this is a web application complicates the matter as there is no state for the web and locking entities for an in-definate amount of time is a bad idea. perhaps a visual indicator the record is locked would be a better starting point. all told I would opt for optimistic concurrency.